# Fan Conversions of 3.5 Adventures to Pathfinder

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, published-adventures

I've recently noticed how cheaply I can get some 3.5 adventures now that everyone has moved to Pathfinder or 4e. I was wondering if there were any collections of fan conversions of them to pathfinder, so I don't have to rework all the statblocks myself. Specifically I'm looking at the Eberron ones and adventure paths, but I'm interested in any conversion.

Comment: Actually, reworking the stat blocks isn't really that bad. Most of the time, you combine Hide/Move Silently = Stealth, Listen/Spot = Perception, and then give them a CMB and a CMD. A lot of the time that is really all you have to do. NPCs with prestige classes are a bit trickier, as would be adding some shiny abilities to things with PC levels, but all and all it's pretty nice. This however, does not answer your question. :)

Comment: Ditto to what @Cthos says.  I've run Rappan Athuk and my wife is running Castle Whiterock and really the only thing we change is what he listed.  If grappling is involved it's a little trickier to convert from 3.5 but not too challenging.  Something to be aware of is that Pathfinder characters tend to be somewhat more powerful then their 3.5 equivalents.

Comment: Ok, I'll admit it: My DM just decided to go back to school as part of a career change, so he doesn't have much time any more. As such he wants to run an adventure path so that he doesn't have to do as much prep work, and I would love to be able to talk him into doing something Eberron, but that isn't going to happen if he has to convert statblocks, as there are pathfinder APs he can just buy, ready to play.

Comment: The only prep time either of us need to put in was reading the actual adventure (which you'd have to do anyway to run it).  All the conversions can be done on the fly or with a quick consultation of the core rules or the online SRD.  No needing to re-write stat blocks or anything.

Comment: If one of you write that up as an answer I'll upvote it, though I'm not going to accept it in the hope I get a answer with preconverted stat blocks. I saw such things for 3e->3.5 products, so I'm hoping there are the same things for 3.5->PF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pathfinder doesn't require major conversions to use D&D 3.5 adventures.  Pathfinder is designed to allow conversion essentially on the fly.  As long as the DM has a decent understanding of Pathfinder and D&D switching between the two should be almost seemless.  I've run several D&D adventures (Rappan Athuk and World's Largest Dungeon) without needing to directly convert stat blocks.  The prep time would not have changed a bit if I'd run them as written for D&D 3.5.